# No handler found for portlet request: mode 'view', phase 'RENDER_PHASE', parameters map[[empty]]

Tags: java, spring, portlet, spring-portlet-mvc

This question has already an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28629225/no-handler-found-for-portlet-request-mode-view-phase-render-phase) but i've checked and the component:scan is set roperly for me so i don't really get what is the point here. The controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("view")
public class PortletController {

@RenderMapping
    public String view(RenderRequest request, RenderResponse response, ModelMap model) {
        ResourceURL baseResourceUrl = response.createResourceURL();

        model.addAttribute("ajaxURL", baseResourceUrl.toString() + "&");
        model.addAttribute("standalone", false);
        model.addAttribute("portletId", getPortletId(request));
        model.addAttribute("portletAppContextPath", request.getContextPath() + "/");

        return "index";
    }
```

The component scan element in the applicationcontext is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">

    <!-- DispatcherPortlet Context: defines this portlet's request-processing infrastructure -->

    <!-- Autodetect annotated controllers -->

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.package.of.controller"/>
</beans>
```

Any idea of why it could be not working?